# Asserting prop call for form submit in React using React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

You can reproduce the problem in the following codesandbox:

[image: Edit Continuous Meme Delivery]

As an example I've made a component which uses the following code to get a random image each time the form button is clicked:

```
import { Button } from "antd";
...
class ContinuousMemeDeliveryApi extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  static defaultProps = { getImage };
  state = { image: images[0], random: 0 };

  handleClick = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { data } = await this.props.getImage();
    this.setState({ image: data.image, random: data.random });
  };
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleClick}>
        <Button htmlType="submit">Click Me</Button>
        ...
      </form>
    );
  }
```

This works as expected, and I've made the following code to test the implementation:

```
test("loads random memes on click", async () => {
  const mockGetImage = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ data: { image: "testImage.jpg" } })
  );
  const { getByText } = render(
    <ContinuousMemeDeliveryApi getImage={mockGetImage} />
  );

  const clickMeButton = getByText(/click/i);

  fireEvent.click(clickMeButton);
  // @TODO: fix assertion
  expect(mockGetImage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

However the test fails with the following error message:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.
```

Any ideas on why this is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 2 react roots rendering within the same document (your application and tests) you can't use default `document.body` as base element for react testing library.

With current approach your queries actually find elements within your application not within the rendered test because they are bound to  [`baseElement = document.body`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/blob/master/src/index.js#L50) and your `div#container` comes first. That is why mock is not being called at all.

[image: Working Example]

You could add additional container to isolate test DOM tree

```
// index.html
<div id="test-container"></div>
```

Now you could specify container when rendering a test

```
import { render as rtlRender, fireEvent, wait } from "react-testing-library";

// get the container
const container = document.getElementById('test-container')

// override render to provide custom container
const render = (ui, options = {}) => rtlRender(ui, { container, ...options })
```